# What to use instead of JFace Actions (since they are deprecated)?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm writing some Java SWT interface and need a menu that changes depending on what is selected on a tree. I found that to manipulate the menu in this fashion I should use MenuManager. To do so, I must use Actions.

Here it says Actions and Contributions are deprecated: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjface_actions.htm

What should I do instead? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285089

It seems it was deprecated in favor of Commands: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework

Nothing in the Eclipse docs points to this.